# Haskell Function to get the List representation of an Integral

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

This is a simple practice problem. The task is to write a function `getLR` that receives an `Integral`, `n`, and returns a list representation (LR) of `n`. For example: `73847 -> [7,3,8,4,7]`. Negative numbers return the LR of the absolute value, for example: `-837 -> [8,3,7]`. In the following code I use three helper functions `getAbs`, `getI` and `getList`:

```
getLR :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
getLR n = if n==0 then [0] else getAbs n

getAbs :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
getAbs n = if n>=0 then getI n n 0 else getI (-n) (-n) 0

-- Computes the length of an Integer and stores it in i, for example 321 has length 3, 9999 has length 4. 
getI :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a -> [a]
getI n m i = if m==0 then getList n [] (i-1) else getI n (m`div`10) (i+1)

-- Constructs the LR recursively.
getList :: (Integral a) => a -> [a] -> a -> [a]
getList n ns i = if n==0 then ns else getList (n-10^i*(n`div`(10^i))) (ns++[n`div`(10^i)]) (i-1)
```

The code works correctly. My specific concerns are readability and simplicity of the code. If you have any suggestions how to make the code more readable or more simple I'd be happy to receive your feedback. If you find any problems besides readability and simplicity: don't hesitate to point them out as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Haskell programmer, but let me just point out a few things here.

First, expressions such as `` (n-10^i*(n`div`(10^i))) `` look quite cluttered. One thing you can do is just put a space between each operator and its operands, and with longer expressions, you can extract pieces and bind them to names to make it easier to understand what's going on. For example, you use `10^i` multiple times. Perhaps you could use `let fac = 10 ^ i in...` to make it clearer what's happening.

Second, the names of these methods are a bit unclear. `getAbs` seems like it would return the absolute value instead of returning the list representation of a number's absolute value. Honestly, I would inline it as part of `getLR`. `getLR`'s meaning isn't immediately clear, and I think `listRepr` or simply `digits` is a clearer name for it. Similarly, `getI` doesn't tell you what it does unless you read the comment above it. I would suggest using `where` to "hide" it, along with `getList`.

However, I think your implementation is a little complicated. All you need is to build up a list of digits, starting at the last digit, by using `` x `mod` 10 `` to get the next digit and `` x `div` 10 `` to get the rest of the number. Here's a solution that I find much simpler:

```
digits :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
digits 0 = [0]
digits n = go (abs n) [] where
  go 0 digs = digs
  go x digs = go (x `div` 10) (x `mod` 10 : digs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, this can be solved with no math at all. The things to know are:

1. `show` turns an `Int` into a `String`
2. A `String` is internally actually `[Char]`, so you can `map` to and from strings as you would lists.
3. `read` converts a `String` to the datatype it represents (but does not work with `Char`s)

Putting those together, the steps to turn an integer into a list of integers is:

1. `show` it
2. Turn each character in the string into a string itself
3. `map` a function with the signature `String -> Int`

```hs
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits = map (read :: String -> Int) . map (:[]) . show
```

Running in a repl:

```hs
> let digits = map (read :: String -> Int) . map (:[]) . show
> digits 73487
=> [7,3,4,8,7]
```

**Update to make it work for both Ints and Integers**

```hs
digits :: (Integral a, Show a, Read a) => a -> [a]
digits = map (read . (:[])) . show
```

Running in a repl:

```hs
> digits :: (Integral a, Show a, Read a) => a -> [a]
  digits = map (read . (:[])) . show

> digits (12345::Int)
=> [1,2,3,4,5]
> digits (12345::Integer)
=> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: nice solution. however it seems to only work when `digits` receives `Int`. when passing the type `Integer` it doesn't seem to work, i.e. can you make it work with `digits :: Integer -> [Integer]`?

Comment: Not at first pass, but I'll give it another go later!

Comment: @MoritzWolff Okay, it took me a while but it ended up being way easier than I thought... Just needed a different type signature.

Comment: This is nice for some cases, but less general than OP's solution. Not only does it not work for types that don't implement `Show` and `Read`, but it also makes assumptions about `show` and `read` that don't hold in general. For an example of the latter, look at `Identity Int` (where `Identity` is from `Data.Functor.Identity`) - `getLR (Identity 123)` is `[Identity 1, Identity 2, Identity 3]`, but `digits (Identity 123)` fails to produce a value

Comment: This looks like a good, concise approach too, but you might want to tack on `. abs` at the end of the `digits` function so that it works with negative numbers

Comment: It's a concise approach, and I do like it otherwise I wouldn't have posted it, but I hesitate to call it *good* as it uses twice the memory of the accepted answer on longer integers.